# Error: Invalid value for module argument The given value is not suitable for child module variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the following error:

```
The given value is not suitable for child module variable "subnets" defined at modules/efs/variables.tf:28,1-19: list of string required.
```

This is how I am calling my EFS module:

```
module "efs_media" {
  source          = "./modules/efs"
  namespace       = "eg"
  stage           = "test"
  name            = var.efs_names[1]
  region          = var.region
  vpc_id          = module.vpc.config.vpc_id
  subnets         = module.vpc.config.private_subnet_ids
  security_groups = [module.cluster.config.node_security_group]
}
```

and below is the VPC output file:

```
output "config" {
  value = {
    vpc_id             = aws_vpc.network.id
    public_subnet_ids  = { for az, subnet in aws_subnet.public : az => subnet.id }
    private_subnet_ids = { for az, subnet in aws_subnet.private : az => subnet.id }
  }
}
```

and this is the main output file:

```
output "vpc_config" {
  value = module.vpc.config
}

output "iam_config" {
  value = module.iam.config
}

output "cluster_config" {
  value = module.cluster.config
}

output "odic_config" {
  value = module.cluster.odic_config
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module output `private_subnet_ids` is a map of `az`: `subnet.id`. Your `efs_media` module wants a list of subnet IDs only which is asking for a list of strings as shown by the error message in the question.

You can turn a map into a list of its values by using the [`values` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html). So in your case you could call your `efs_media` module like this:

```
module "efs_media" {
  source          = "./modules/efs"
  namespace       = "eg"
  stage           = "test"
  name            = var.efs_names[1]
  region          = var.region
  vpc_id          = module.vpc.config.vpc_id
  subnets         = values(module.vpc.config.private_subnet_ids)
  security_groups = [module.cluster.config.node_security_group]
}
```